# Flask SQL-Alchemy | MySql - Multiple Foreign Keys issues

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)


class Devices(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'devices'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    purpose = db.Column('purpose', db.String(64))
    type = db.Column('type', db.String(64))
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(64))
    channel = db.Column('channel', db.Integer)
    role_id = db.Column('role_id', db.Integer)
    role_permissions = db.Column('role_permissions', db.Integer)
    role = db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['role_id', 'role_permissions'], ['roles.id', 'roles.permissions'])
```

Then I would expect this to work:

```
dev = Devices(purpose="lights",type="tcp",name="zeus",channel=8)
role = Role.query.first()
dev.role = role
db.session.add(dev)
db.session.commit()
```

But once persisted, role_id and role_permissions get null value. Why? Whats the right way to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a relationship in addition to the foreign key.

A foreign key is just a database-level constraint to ensure you cannot reference rows that don't exist (additionally, it helps SQLAlchemy setup a relationship without you specifying another time how the two tables are linked).

You want this in your model:

```
class Devices(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = (db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['role_id', 'role_permissions'], ['roles.id', 'roles.permissions']),)
    # ...
    role = db.relationship('Role', backref=db.backref('devices'))
```

By doing so, `device.role = some_role` will properly populate the foreign keys, and in addition each Role instance will have a `devices` collection that gives you access to its associated devices.

The SQLAlchemy tutorial also has a section about relationships:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship

You can pretty much follow it; Flask-SQLAlchemy and plain SQLalchemy don't really differ - Flask-SQLAlchemy simply makes many things accessible via the `db` object to avoid importing them explicitly.

---

By the way, since `Role.id` is the primary key, you don't need to include `role_permissions` in the foreign key - you cannot have more than one role the same ID since the primary key is always unique. This makes your model even easier:

```
class Devices(db.Model):
    # ...
    role_id = db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    role = db.relationship('Role', backref=db.backref('devices'))
```

You can also get rid of the `role_permissions` column in your `Devices` model (which, by the way, should be named `Device`). If you need the permissions, simply get it from the role (if you usually need it, add `lazy=False` to the foreign key, then querying a device will always join the role table to avoid extra queries)

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a long time. Can't thank you enough

Comment: I am doing this because my app uses Flask-REST so its easier to have all the data I need in a single json object. I am also building a many-to-many relationship between Users and Devices using an UserDevices model, and got stuck doing nearly the same thing. So I might have some other issues soon. lol THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Can't you tell flask-rest to get it from `device.role.permissions` instead of `device.role_permissions`? Anyway, a simply property that returns `self.role.permissions` would do the job, too